# Using 64 bits integers with Perl XS

Tags: c, perl, xs

I want to port a C function using 64 bits integers to Perl code. To do that, I use Perl XS.

My problem is there are no 64 bits integers in Perl XS types (only U32, U16 and U8).

So, what is the best way to use 64 bit integers in Perl XS code?

Here is a code example of what I want to do:

```
uint64_t
foo(integer)
   uint64_t integer

   CODE:
      RETVAL = foo(integer);

   OUTPUT:
      RETVAL
```

foo() has the C prototype:

```
uint64_t foo(uint64_t);
```

I didn't find anything useful in the perlxs documentation and in stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I don't know Perl (XS), but if tthe language does not provide integers larger than 32 bit, you cannot "use 64 bit integers". It's the same as if you have no hammer, you cannot use a hammer. Only way might be to use two 32 bit variables and program the required operations yourself, but that is not trivial. (Sidenote: `U32` etc sounds like unsigned, while the term _integer_ normally includes the negative range)

Comment: NVs can represent precisely integers up to 2**53. In practice that is enough in quite a few cases, otherwise use `Math::Int64` as advised bellow.

Answer (score 6):

Perl's internal type for unsigned integers is `UV`. If your platform has 64-bit UVs, you should be fine.

With 32-bit UVs (32-bit OS and Perl was compiled without use64bitint), you can convert large integers to and from floating point numbers (`NV` which is typically a `double`). But since IEEE doubles only have 53 bits of mantissa, this will cause a loss of precision for large numbers.

```c
uint64_t integer;

// Convert uint64_t to SV.

if (integer <= UV_MAX) {
    RETVAL = newSVuv((UV)integer);
}
else {
    RETVAL = newSVnv((NV)integer);
}

// Convert SV to uint64_t with range checks.

if (SvUOK(sv)) {
    integer = (uint64_t)SvUV(sv);
}
else if (SvIOK(sv)) {
    IV iv = SvIV(sv);
    if (iv < 0) croak(...);
    integer = (uint64_t)iv;
}
else if (SvNOK(sv)) {
    NV nv = SvNV(sv);
    if (nv < 0.0 || nv >= 18446744073709551616.0) croak(...);
    integer = (uint64_t)nv;
}
else {
    // Parse a uint64_t from the string value, or whatever.
}
```

If you can't live with loss of precision and want to support 32-bit UVs, you can use the [C API](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Int64#C-API) of `Math::Int64` (also see [`Module::CAPIMaker`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::CAPIMaker#USAGE-OF-THE-C-API-FROM-OTHER-MODULES)):

```
#define MATH_INT64_NATIVE_IF_AVAILABLE
#include "perl_math_int64.h"

MODULE = ...

BOOT:
    PERL_MATH_INT64_LOAD_OR_CROAK;

SV*
foo(args...)
CODE:
    uint64_t integer = ...
    RETVAL = newSVu64(integer);
OUTPUT:
    RETVAL
```

With a typemap like

```
TYPEMAP
uint64_t T_UINT64

INPUT
T_UINT64
    $var = SvU64($arg)

OUTPUT
T_UINT64
    $arg = newSVu64($var);
```

you can use `uint64_t` directly in your XS:

```
uint64_t
foo(arg)
    uint64_t arg
```

Answer (score 5):

The `uint64_t` type is not defined in default `typemap`, that comes with Perl distribution. According to [`perlxstypemap`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstypemap.html):

> In more practical terms, the typemap is a collection of code fragments
>   which are used by the `xsubpp` compiler to map C function parameters and
>   values to Perl values.

You can define your own `typemap` (in the same directory as `.xs` file). It might look like:

```
TYPEMAP
unsigned long long T_U_LONG_LONG
uint64_t T_U_LONG_LONG              # equivalent to typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;

INPUT
T_U_LONG_LONG
    $var = (unsigned long long)SvUV($arg)

OUTPUT
T_U_LONG_LONG
    sv_setuv($arg, (UV)$var);
```

I am not sure about these mappings, especially `SvUV` and `UV` part, so you need to test it carefully in any real code. I suspect that they are just "plain" integers, thus `uint64_t` is fully functional only for internal usage, that is within function's definition.

Note that `unsigned long long` type is *at least* 64-bits wide according to C Standard (since C99), but it's 64-bit on every implementation I am aware of.

With `test.xs` as:

```
#include "EXTERN.h"
#include "perl.h"
#include "XSUB.h"
#include "ppport.h"

MODULE = test       PACKAGE = test

unsigned int
u64_mul_high(a, b)
    unsigned int a
    unsigned int b
CODE:
    RETVAL = ((uint64_t) a * b) >> 32;
OUTPUT:
    RETVAL
```

and `test.pl` defined as:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use ExtUtils::testlib;
use test;

print test::u64_mul_high(2147483647, 1000), "\n";
```

you get an result of:

```
499 (0001 1111 0011)
```

that is higher 32-bit limb of an `32-bit x 32-bit` multiplication that results into 64-bit integer.

I checked this on 32-bit GNU/Linux with `sizeof(long) = 4` and Perl 5.10.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ perl -MConfig -le 'print $Config{use64bitint}'
```

will show if your `perl` was compiled to use 64 bit integers. If so, IV is 64-bit.

See also [perldoc perlguts](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlguts#What-is-an-IV):

> #### What is an "IV"?
>
> Perl uses a special typedef IV which is a simple signed integer type that is guaranteed to be large enough to hold a pointer (as well as an integer). Additionally, there is the UV, which is simply an unsigned IV.
>
> Perl also uses two special typedefs, I32 and I16, which will always be at least 32-bits and 16-bits long, respectively. (Again, there are U32 and U16, as well.) They will usually be exactly 32 and 16 bits long, but on Crays they will both be 64 bits.

See also [Math::Int64](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Int64):

> This module adds support for 64 bit integers, signed and unsigned, to Perl.
>
> ...
>
> #### Fallback to native 64bit support if available
>
> If the lexical pragma `Math::Int64::native_if_available` is used in your program and the version of perl in use has native support for 64bit integers, the functions imported from the module that create 64bit integers (i.e. `uint64`, `int64`, `string_to_int64`, `native_to_int64`, etc.) will return regular perl scalars.